# What are the "bogus" files in IE's temporary files?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, temporary-files

I'm just running CCleaner to tidy my computer up, and as it was deleting IE's temporary files I noticed a lot of them were named "something_bogus[1]". Why are these files named "bogus"? What's "bogus" about them, and why are they not removed for their bogusness?

Comment: I wonder if it is your security software doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a lot of these bogus files too. They are created alongside the WBKTMP files, which are created from outlook or windows live mail, and they build up a lot.I can open the WBKTMP files with notepad, and it was just email information, and as for the "Bogus" There appears no reason for them. They have no data, 0 bytes total. I just deleted 250 of them, and all 250 still amounted to 0 bytes. I delete them by Organize/folder n search options, then "view", "Show all hidden folders files and drives" in folder options, then open temporary int file folder by opening disk cleanup, and the 2nd one down is the one, and the box at the bottom "Show files" When in, right click and "Sort by" "Size" All the bogus will be at the bottom where they can be deleted together. There are many other (and easier) ways I suppose, but that's mine. Of course you can just delete them with CCleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nothing. I assume that what you're seeing is the name of the file, not a description per se. Therefore, for example, I could create a picture in Photoshop showing a mouse is bigger than an elephant and call it bogus01. My guess is this is the same, but it may not be graphical, it could be a session name or similar.

To be honest, the best way I can help further (if you need) is if you can take a screen shot.